# Passing variable to sed for while loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, variables, sed

I want to loop over a file starting from the n th line using shell sed,I could make it work for an integer (example below starting from line 5), but I want to replace the integer by an sys argument variable :  linesToBegin= $1

Here is the code:

```
sed -n '5,$ p' twitter_ids.txt | while read linecontent
do
            echo $linecontent 
done
```

When I replace the number 5 by linesToBegin:

```
sed -n '$linesToBegin,$ p' twitter_ids.txt | while read linecontent
```

I get an error saying

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after comman
```

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables, double quotes do.

Comment: You may be starting out on the wrong foot with the shell loop. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Also, using `tail -n +"$linesToBegin"` would make a lot more sense than using `sed` to tail a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
linesToBegin="$1"
sed -n "$linesToBegin,\$ p" twitter_ids.txt | while read linecontent
do
            echo "$linecontent"
done
```

Should probably work now. Just need double quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me, giving me : sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'

Comment: @goodboy, surprising, works correctly on my machine..

Comment: Ok, now it is working,  the problem was a little space in the assignment in the sys arg variable that i did not notice !

Comment: `echo "$linecontent"` is better, the line can be a special character like `*`.  More standard is using curly braces like `echo "${linecontent}"`.

Comment: That should be `while IFS= read -r linecontent`. @WalterA you're right about the quotes but when just referencing scalar variables curly braces are only for when you need to separate the variable name from other alphanumeric text, e.g. `echo "${foo}bar"`, there's no need to use them otherwise. If you were doing a substitution like `echo "${foo#*.}"` or using an array like `echo "${foo[@]}"` then you'd use them but that's not the case here.